# Should a capital letter be used after an ellipsis?

Tags: punctuation, capitalization, ellipses

I was talking to a friend of mine over Skype, and I typed this:

> Ok... Now I want more pork pie.

I'd like to know, should there be a capital letter after the ellipsis "…"? Should it be written the way I typed it:

> Ok... Now I want more pork pie.

Or should it be a lowercase "n":

> Ok... now I want more pork pie.

Do ellipses break a sentence so that a new one must be started after them (hence the capital "N"), or do they behave similarly to commas and dashes in that they serve as a "pause", with a lowercase "n"?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipsis

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Most *writers* would use a comma in OP's example, not an ellipsis. So the issue wouldn't arise there anyway. Probably the writer intended *"Okay...blah blah"* to make the reader "internally vocalise" it as *"Okaaaaaay, blah blah"*.

In general, it really depends on whether you consider the ellipsis represents an "empty" pause at the end of a preceding sentence. If so, what follows is a new sentence, and it starts with a capital letter.

If you think the ellipsis represents a *delay within an as-yet-incomplete sentence*, but you've decided you don't want indicate that delay using some other punctuation (comma, semicolon, etc.), then just continue the sentence without a capital.

Effectively, it's partly the exact context, and partly stylistic preference. I'd say if in doubt, consider using a comma instead of an ellipsis. If that doesn't feel right, you should probably capitalise.

Answer (score 20):

The first word after an ellipsis is capitalized if it begins a new grammatical sentence.¹

¹Chicago Manual of Style, [13.51](http://www.chicagomanualofstyle.org/16/ch13/ch13_toc.html).

Comment: In the example, "now" does not definitely begin a new sentence, so your rule does not definitely apply. For example the ellipse in the example may represent an intentional silence in the middle of the sentence (replacing a comma). In that case the word "now" does not take an initial capital.

Comment: While I think you are mostly right, I would add that there is an element of writer intent. Therefore in the OP's example, 'now' *could* be capitalized, not must be. It depends on if the writer is aiming more for "Ok, now I want..." or "Ok. Now I want...".

Comment: @chaiguy yes you are right I edited my answer. In the light of the cmos' statement the user can decide if s/he has to capitalize or not.

Comment: In that case, there should be four dots, three for the ellipsis and one for the period.

Comment: @DjangoReinhardt that's what I learned in school. Don't know if the rules have changed since then.

Comment: @asmeurer You know what, you're absolutely right. Sorry, I was completely wrong about that. My bad.

Answer (score -1):

All of your answers are correct, but it is up to the person writing the sentence. If he/she wants to emphasize a word then he/she would use a capital letter on the next word.

Comment: How can all of the other answers be correct if it's always up to the writer? And I don't think capitalizing the first word of a sentence places particular emphasis on that first word; could you explain why you think capitalization in this case is a form of emphasis?