# Capital After an Ellipsis

Tags: punctuation, capitalization, ellipses

In a British/Australian English is there a capital placed after every ellipsis or are there conditional rules?

For example, “Even his speech… (“P” or “p”)itched so that everyone outside his door could hear…” or “It wasn’t to discuss my daughter… (“N” or “n”)o no no…”

Comment: Is the word that follows the start of a new sentence (put it in capitals) or is it the continuation of the same sentence (leave it in lowercase). If it's a quotation, then most style guides say you can silently change the case to fit the running text. (Otherwise, change it but enclose it in square brackets to indicate you've changed it.) There isn't enough detail provided in the question to know the specific context here.

Comment: Makes sense -- I'll apply those rules :)

Comment: I only have access to the American English *Chicago Manual of Style*. I believe the rule is: 1) if it's three dots and indicates hesitation is speech, it's not capitalized. *"Even his speech... pitched so everyone outside the door could hear... was incomprehensible."* 2) if it is a complete sentence, and whole sentences were omitted, then it's four dots. The new sentence is capitalized, as usual. *"It wasn't to discuss my daughter.... My son is the real subject."*

Comment: Related/possible duplicate: [Should a capital letter be used after an ellipsis?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/73524/50590)